# Re-read what the method is supposed to be, do my code look about right?

Tags: java

I just re-read what the method is supposed to do:

- Add the give Picture at the end and the method insert it at the position given by the "where" parameter value. Value should between 0 - nPictsInAlbum
- When it is 0, the Picture is inserted at the beginning and the other Pictures are shifted right to make space for the Picture.
- nPictsInAlbum add the given Picture at the end

```
public boolean addPicture(Picture thePicture, int where) {
    int index = where;
    while (index < nPictsInAlbum) {
        pictArray[index - 1] = thePicture;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You need to shift all your elements to the right first, and then insert at the appropriate position. Also, you need to update the `index` in the loop also.

Answer (score 2):

You don't update `index` in the loop, so it is an infinite loop (if entered at all).

Start with `index = nPictsInAlbum`; assign `pictArray[index] = pictArray[index-1]`. Do it while `index > where`; then finish off with `pictArray[where] = thePicture`.

Don't forget to update `nPictsInAlbum++`!

Comment: Also, there is a logical problem with the code. OP is simply overwriting the existing element with the new element.